# Persisting a Large List for Membership Testing in C

Tags: c, persistence, membership, large-data

Each item is an array of 17 32-bit integers. I can probably produce 120-bit unique hashes for them.

I have an algorithm that produces 9,731,643,264 of these items, and want to see how many of these are unique. I speculate that at most 1/36th of these will be unique but can't be sure.

At this size, I can't really do this in memory (as I only have 4 gigs), so I need a way to persist a list of these, do membership tests, and add each new one if it's not already there.

I am working in C(gcc) on Linux so it would be good if the solution can work from there.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you're comfortable with C++, take a look at http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Have you looked at using a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)?

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of some of the problems I faced working on a solution to "Knight's Tour" many years ago.  (A math problem which is now solved, but not by me.)

Even your hash isn't that much help . . . at the nearly the size of a GUID, they could easily be unique accross all the the known universe.

It will take approximately .75 Terrabytes just to hold the list on disk . . . 4 Gigs of memory or not, you'd still need a huge disk just to hold them.  And you'd need double that much disk or more to do the sort/merge solutions I talk about below.

If you could SORT that list, then you could just go threw the list one item at a time looking for unique copies next to each other.  Of course sorting that much data would required a custom sort routine (that you wrote) since it is binary (coverting to hex would double the size of your data, but would allow you to use standard routines) . . . though likely even there they would probably choke on that much data . . . so your are back to your own custom routines.

Some things to think about:

1. Sorting that much data will take weeks, months or perhaps years.  While you can do a nice heap sort or whatever in memory, because you only have so much disk space, you will likely be doing a "bubble" sort of the files regardless of what you do in memory.
2. Depending on what your generation algorithm looks like, you could generate "one memory load" worth of data, sort it in place then write it out to disk in a file (sorted).  Once that was done, you just have to "merge" all those individual sorted files, which is a much easier task (even thought there would be 1000s of files, it would still be a relatively easier task).
3. If your generator can tell you ANYTHING about your data, use that to your advantage.  For instance in my case, as I processed the Knight's Moves, I know my output values were constantly getting bigger (because I was always adding one bit per move), that small knowledge allowed me to optimize my sort in some unique ways.  Look at your data, see if you know anything similar.
4. Making the data smaller is always good of course.  For instance you talk about a 120 hash, but is that has reversable?  If so, sort the hash since it is smaller.  If not, the hash might not be that much help (at least for my sorting solutions).

I am interested in the machanics of issues like this and I'd be happy to exchange emails on this subject just to bang around ideas and possible solutions.

Comment: Well, you're right on the money as to the type of problem, I'm trying to solve the 17x17 (http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2009/11/17x17-challenge-worth-28900-this-is-not.html). My 120bit hash is indeed reversible. In fact, I may be able to make it smaller with more thought, this is from just a first aproximation. My email is al3xgr@gmail.com email me yours and I can give you more details on that I'm doing. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make your life a lot easier if you can place some restrictions on your input data: Even assuming only 120 significant bits, the high number of duplicate values suggests an uneven distribution, as an even distribution would make duplicates unlikely for a given sample size of `10^10`:

```
2^120 = (2^10)^12 > (10^3)^12 = 10^36 >> 10^10
```

If you have continuous clusters (instead of sparse, but repeated values), you can gain a lot by operating on ranges instead of atomic values.

What I would do:

- fill a buffer with a batch of generated values
- sort the buffer in-memory
- write ranges to disk, ie each entry in the file consists of start and end value of a continuous group of values

Then, you need to merge the individual files, which can be done online - ie as the files become available - the same way a stack-based mergesort operates: associate to each file a counter equal to the number of ranges in the file and push each new file on a stack. When the file on top of the stack has a counter greater or equal to the previous file, merge the files into a new file whose counter is the number of ranges in the merged file.

Comment: Great insights, thanks. Given my data, I should expect that 34 bits would be enough, and given that I have at least 36 duplicates per unique item (the goal is to see if there's more), that should bring it down to 29 bits. That's a -much- better number to target. I'm not sure if ranges will come into it.